# MEF Issue: I Can't see the Imported Class

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef

Our application implements MVVM-WPF-Unity and I adding a feature that will add plugins in our application thru MEF. Thus I have a Plugin Manager class and plugin class.

In the Plugin class  module, I have this.

```cs
namespace project.plugin
{
    [Export("Module",typeof(IModule))]
    public class Plugin : IModule
    {
       private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

       private readonly IUnityContainer container;
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]         
    public Module(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterViewsAndServices();
    }
}
```

Inside my Plugin Manager I did this:

```cs
[ImportMany] 
public IEnumerable<Lazy<IModule>> ImportedModules { get; set; }

AggregateCatalog moduleCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(
    new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(IModule).Assembly),
    new DirectoryCatalog("Plugins"));
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(moduleCatalog);
container.ComposeParts(this);



foreach (IModule iModule in ImportedModules)
{                    
    iModule.Initialize();
}
```

The problem here is that ImportedModules seems to be empty although as I looked in my container catalog I can see the plugin class has been exported. Help please please please

Comment: You're Exporting a contract name "Module" explicitly, but your ImportMany does not specify the same contract name (it's using the implicit contract named associated with `IModule`.)

Comment: thanks Dan, I'll edit my ImportMany attribute and add the contract name.

Comment: after I have successfully imported the modules, I plan of creating a tree view and load every plugin there and show the view once the corresponding node has been click from the tree view. Any help about this will be very much appreciated. sorry about this question, I am a neophyte with C#. :(